# Arrays not working with echo

Tags: php

I have the code below in a WordPress template that generates the array `$meta`:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$query = ("SELECT ID, post_password, post_name
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_password = 'listing'");

$listings = $wpdb->get_results( $query, OBJECT);

foreach($listings as $listing) {
    $meta = get_post_meta($listing->ID,'' ,true);
    $meta = array_map(function($n) {return $n[0];}, $meta);
    echo "<br /> listing->ID = $listing->ID"; 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($meta);
    echo "</pre>"; 
    $first_name = $meta['first_name'];
    $last_name = $meta['last_name'];
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $meta['first_name']; ?>
    </td>
```

The print_r($meta) above prints out

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => John
    [last_name] => Jones
    [business_name] => 
    [phone] => 208 324-6916
    [email] => johnjones@yahoo.com
    [page_name] => 
    [barcode_number] => 
    [website] => 
    [header] => 
    [description_1] => 
    [description_2] => 
    [footer] => 
)
```

I want to echo these values into a table cell. If I write

```
    <td>
        <?php echo $meta['first_name']; ?>
    </td>
```

I get the error: `Notice: Undefined index: first_name in . . .`

But if I do

```
$first_name = $meta['first_name'];
?>
    <td>
        <?php echo $first_name; ?>
    </td>
```

It works.  Does anyone know what's going on?  Thanks.

Comment: Please can you provide full code which you have issue ? I mean where $meta definition done ?

Comment: Way to declare array is wrong way you can declare as Array( 'first_name'=>'John','last_name'=>'Jones') then you will use echo.

Comment: I thought that was the print_r output of $meta @WisdmLabs

Comment: No, this is not an issue, guaranteed. `$meta` is not what you think it is on the `echo ..` line; no more, no less. `var_dump($meta)` ***immediately*** before `echo`. My guess is that you're overwriting `$meta` in-between checking its contents and `echo`.

Comment: I edited the question to show how $meta is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be accidentally overwriting $meta variable somewhere between assignment and output. Print the full array

```
<td>
    <?php var_dump($meta); ?>
</td>
```

and compare it with the one you defined. You may be surprised that it's not what you've set before or not even an array anymore. This can happen implicitly, with functions like extract() etc.

Comment: (edited after your generation snippet) you're overwriting $meta var every time, so your <tr> output should be in the same foreach $listings loop, because you'll only have the last variable after it, or put it into some temporary array and loop over that array afterwards, when you generate <td>s

Answer (score 0):

Let's reproduce your array, fully tested (PHP 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5):

```
$meta = [
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Jones',
    'business_name' => '',
    'phone' => '208 324-6916',
    'email' => 'johnjones@yahoo.com',
    'page_name' => '',
    'barcode_number' => '', 
    'website' => '',
    'header' => '',
    'description_1' => '',
    'description_2' => '',
    'footer' => ''
];

echo $meta['first_name']; // John
```

So I think you don't assign right your array to $meta. Copy above and test.

### Is it old code on an old server?

Ok, *I never say this*, but possibly, you maintain very old code on a very old server. In that way, I can set de error level lower.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: I ran a var_dump($meta) from inside the <td> and the array is still there.

Comment: Right, what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry.  I was responding to the suggestions farther up that the $meta array had gone away before I referred to it inside of the <td></td> tags. It doesn't look like it.  As far as old code goes, I don't think so.  The server is at wpengine running running WordPress 4.3.2 and PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: I have this working now.  The problem was that one of the records I was pulling from the DB was corrupted.  The next one was ok so it looked like the data was ok, but it was the first one that threw the error.  Since Oleg had the first answer to say that the data wasn't there anymore, I gave it to him.